Is it feasible to dynamically add specific headers to a single page within an Angular SPA application when served from the server?
I'm concerned that since Angular's routing is handled client-side, this might not be directly possible or is it?
I attempted to add headers on my local Angular server as follows:


          "options": {
            "headers": {
              "Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy": "require-corp",
              "Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy": "same-origin"
            }
          }

This resulted in CORS errors for all app resources loading from different origins. Given that Angular routers operate client-side, I'm exploring options to achieve server-side rendering for a specific single page. I need to apply the above headers to that path both locally and when deploying with Cloudflare.
